# Can't Overload << Operator on 64-bit Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, 64-bit

I am developing with Qt and strongHercul struct has members defined as `uint64_t min` and `uint64_t max` (I just don't want to use quint64 for this).
While trying to overload << operator as below.

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &ds, const strongHercul& hercul)
{
    ds << hercul.min << hercul.max;
    return ds;
}
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &ds, strongHercul& hercul)
{
    ds >> hercul.min >> hercul.max;
    return ds;
}
```

I got following error:

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' 
(operand types are 'QDataStream' and 'const uint64_t {aka const long unsigned int}')
     data_stream << hercul.min << hercul.max;
                 ^
error: no match for 'operator>>' 
(operand types are 'QDataStream' and 'uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}')
 data_stream >> hercul.min >> hercul.max;
             ^
```

Didn't really understand what's wrong? I assume that might cause 64-bit system that I'm running cause this code works smoothly on 32-bit Windows?
The question is how to overload while using `uint64_t`?

Comment: How is uint64_t defined?

Comment: Does that code work when you copy it to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of it, `QDataStream` doesn't have overloads for `uint64_t`. As a result the output operator tries to convert to one of multiple choices, i.e., there is an ambiguity and for the input operator a non-`const` reference is required and there is no matching operator. You should probably travel in terms of `quint64` which seems to be a `unsigned long long int` while it seems `uint64_t` is a `unsigned long int`.

Comment: In other words, the data needs to be cast to `quint64`: `ds << (quint64)hercul.min << (quint64)hercul.max;`